# How to force converter into not serializing primitive types type data?

Tags: android, xml, retrofit, simple-framework

I'm using Retrofit together with SimpleXMLConverter but there's one thing I can't work out with annotations, namely:

When I serialize a class that has a double member, it's wrapped in `<double>` tags and I want it:

```
@Root(name = "WrappedDouble", strict = false)
public class WrappedDouble {
    @Element(name = "theRealDoubleField")
    double classField;
}
```

Serializing such a class would give

```
<WrappedDouble>
    <theRealDoubleField>
        <double>3.0</double>
    </theRealDoubleField>
</WrappedDouble>
```

Is there a way to make these tags disappear?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Simple are you using? Using ***2.7.1*** and this code:

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
WrappedDouble wd = new WrappedDouble(27.23);
serializer.write(wd, System.out); // Write to stdout
```

i get the following (correct) result:

```
<WrappedDouble>
   <theRealDoubleField>27.23</theRealDoubleField>
</WrappedDouble>
```

For the sake of completeness, here's the implementation i used for testing:

```
@Root(name = "WrappedDouble", strict = false)
public class WrappedDouble
{
    @Element(name = "theRealDoubleField")
    double classField;


    public WrappedDouble(double d)
    {
        this.classField = d;
    }

    WrappedDouble()
    {
        this(0.0);
    }


    public double getClassField()
    {
        return classField;
    }
}
```

---

Are you using any custom *Transformer*, *Converter* or *Strategies*?